# How to make a rest call in Azure pipeline then use the response to make another call?

Tags: api, rest, azure-devops

I am creating an Azure pipeline where I need to make a rest api call from the pipeline then use part of the api call response in the request of another consecutive rest api call.
How can I achieve that?

Comment: Hi arsany, any update?

Answer (score 0):

In my test, I use the script below to get the work item state value in the pipeline, and you could use this variable in your script or pipeline for other api calls.

> 1.I transfer the api result into json with variable `$field`
>
> 2.Write-host the value `$field`
>
> 3.Get the element of system.state and set it as variable `$witstate`
>
> 4.Write-host the value.

[image]

```
# Define organization base url, PAT, linked wit, Target WIT state and API version variables

$orgUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/{yourORG}/{yourPROJECT}"
$pat = ""
$queryString = "fields=system.state&api-version=7.0"
$witID = {YourWitID}


# Create header with PAT

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($pat)"))
$header = @{authorization = "Basic $token"}


# Get the linked wit state
$projectsUrl = "$orgUrl/_apis/wit/workitems/$witID?$queryString"

$field = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $projectsUrl -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header | ConvertTo-Json | ConvertFrom-Json | Select-Object -ExpandProperty fields

write-host $field

$witstate = $field.'System.State'
Write-Host $witstate
```

[image]